# Haskell profilling subgraph mining algorithm

Tags: haskell, graph, profiling, graph-algorithm

I try to solve problem of finding all connected subgraphs in Haskell. Algorithm used is described [here](http://match.pmf.kg.ac.rs/electronic_versions/Match41/match41_145-149.pdf). Quote from that paper:

> As in every path algorithm, there are forward steps and back steps. A step forward is done if a given connected subgraph can be extended by addition of edge k, that is if edge k is not already part of the given subgraph, if k is adjacent to at least one edge of the given subgraph, and if addition of edge k is not forbidden by some restrictions given below.
>   A step back is done as soon as a given connected subgraph cannot be further elongated. In this case the edge added last is removed from the string, it is temporarily given the status "forbidden", and any other edges which were forbidden by backtracking from a previous longer string are simultaneously "allowed" again. In contrast, an edge which is forbidden by being removed from a string shorter than the present one remains forbidden, thus assuring that every connected subgraph is constructed once and only once.

To do this algorithm, I represented graphs as list of edges:

```
 type Edge =  (Int,Int)
 type Graph = [Edge]
```

Firstly, I wrote function `addEdge` that check if is it possible to extend graph, return `Nothing` if it isn't possible or `Edge` to extend.

I have a `"parent"` graph and `"extensible"` graph, so I try to found one and only one edge that exists in `"parent"` graph, connected with `"extensible"` graph, not already included in `"extensible"` graph and so not included in `forbidden` set.

I wrote this function below:

```
addEdge :: Graph -> Graph -> [Edge] -> Maybe Edge
addEdge !parent !extensible !forb = listToMaybe $ intersectBy (\ (i,j) (k,l) -> (i == k || i == l || j == k || j == l)) (parent \\ (extensible `union` forb)) extensible
```

It's work! but, as I see from profiling whole program, `addEdge` is the most heavy function. I am sure, that my code isn't optimal. Leastways,  `intersectBy` function that finds all possible solutions but i need only one. Is there any ways to make this code more rapid? Maybe, don't use standard lists but `Set` `from Data.Set`? It's first point of attention.

Main recursive function `ext` presented below:

```
ext :: Graph -> [Graph] -> Maybe Graph -> [(Edge,Int)] -> Int -> [Graph]
ext !main !list !grow !forb !maxLength      | isEnd  == True = (filter (\g -> (length g /= 1)) list) ++ (group main) 
                                            | ((addEdge main workGraph forbEdges) == Nothing) || (length workGraph) >= maxLength = ext main list (Just workGraph) forbProcess maxLength
                                            | otherwise = ext main ((addedEdge:workGraph):list) Nothing forb  maxLength where 
                                                workGraph = if grow == Nothing then (head list) else (bite (fromJust grow)) -- [Edge] graph now proceeded
                                                workGraphLength = length workGraph
                                                addedEdge = fromJust  $ addEdge'
                                                addEdge' = addEdge main workGraph forbEdges
                                                bite xz = if (length xz == 1) then (fromJust (addEdge main xz forbEdges)):[] else tail xz 
                                                forbProcess = (head workGraph,workGraphLength):(filter ((<=workGraphLength).snd) forb)
                                                forbEdges = map fst forb -- convert from (Edge,Level) to [Edge]                     
                                                isEnd = (grow /= Nothing) && (length (fromJust grow) == 1) && ((addEdge main (fromJust grow) forbEdges) == Nothing)
```

I test my program on graph

```
c60 = [(1,4),(1,3),(1,2),(2,6),(2,5),(3,10),(3,7),(4,24),(4,21),(5,8),(5,7),(6,28),(6,25),
    (7,9),(8,11),(8,12),(9,16),(9,13),(10,20),(10,17),(11,14),(11,13),(12,28),(12,30),(13,15),
    (14,43),(14,30),(15,44),(15,18),(16,18),(16,17),(17,19),(18,47),(19,48),(19,22),(20,22),(20,21),
    (21,23),(22,31),(23,32),(23,26),(24,26),(24,25),(25,27),(26,35),(27,36),(27,29),(28,29),(29,39),
    (30,40),(31,32),(31,33),(32,34),(33,50),(33,55),(34,37),(34,55),(35,36),(35,37),(36,38),(37,57),
    (38,41),(38,57),(39,40),(39,41),(40,42),(41,59),(42,45),(42,59),(43,44),(43,45),(44,46),(45,51),
    (46,49),(46,51),(47,48),(47,49),(48,50),(49,53),(50,53),(51,52),(52,60),(52,54),(53,54),(54,56),(55,56),(56,58),(57,58),(58,60),(59,60)] :: Graph
```

For example, find all subgraphs with length from 1 to 7

```
length $ ext c60 [[(1,2)]] Nothing [] 7
>102332
```

Problem is too **low speed** of computation. As it pointed in original article, program have been written in `FORTRAN 77` and launched on 150MHz workstation, perform test task minimum 30 times faster then my code on modern i5 processor. 
I can't understand, why my program is so slow? **Is there any ways to refactor this code?** Or the best solution is porting it on C, and write bindings to C library over FFI?

Comment: `(\\)` is slow, O(n^2). Use `Data.Set.(\\)` instead, it is O(n+m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to take a shot at implementing the algorithm described in the paper using [`fgl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl). The complete code follows.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Data.Graph.Inductive
import Data.List
import Data.Tree

uniq = map head . group . sort . map (\(a, b) -> (min a b, max a b))
delEdgeLU (from, to) = delEdge (from, to) . delEdge (to, from)
insEdgeDU (from, to) = insEdge (from, to, ()) . insNodeU to . insNodeU from where
    insNodeU n g = if gelem n g then g else insNode (n, ()) g

nextEdges subgraph remaining
    | isEmpty subgraph = uniq (edges remaining)
    | otherwise = uniq $ do
        n  <- nodes subgraph
        n' <- suc remaining n
        return (n, n')

search_ subgraph remaining
    = Node subgraph
    . snd . mapAccumL step remaining
    $ nextEdges subgraph remaining
    where
    step r e = let r' = delEdgeLU e r in (r', search_ (insEdgeDU e subgraph) r')

search = search_ empty

mkUUGraph :: [(Int, Int)] -> Gr () ()
mkUUGraph es = mkUGraph ns (es ++ map swap es) where
    ns = nub (map fst es ++ map snd es)
    swap (a, b) = (b, a)

-- the one from the paper
sampleGraph = mkUUGraph cPaper
cPaper = [(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

The functions you'll want to use at the top-level are `mkUUGraph`, which constructs a graph from a list of edges, and `search`, which constructs a tree whose nodes are connected subgraphs of its input. For example, to compute the statistics shown at the bottom of "Scheme 1" in the paper, you might do this:

```
*Main> map length . tail . levels . search . mkUUGraph $ [(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
[6,7,8,9,6,1]
*Main> sum it
37
```

I had a little trouble comparing it to your implementation, because I don't understand what all the arguments to `ext` are supposed to do. In particular, I couldn't work out how to call `ext` on the adjacency graph in the paper in such a way that I got 37 results. Perhaps you have a bug.

In any case, I did my best to emulate what I think your code is trying to do: finding graphs with up to seven edges, and certainly containing the edge `(1, 2)` (despite the fact that your code outputs many graphs that do not contain `(1, 2)`). I added this code:

```
mainHim = print . length $ ext c60 [[(1,2)]] Nothing [] 7
mainMe  = print . length . concat . take 7 . levels $ search_ (mkUUGraph [(1,2)]) (mkUUGraph c60)
```

My code finds 3301 such graphs; yours finds 35571. I didn't try very hard to figure out where that discrepancy came from. In ghci, `mainHim` takes 36.45s; `mainMe` takes 0.13s. When compiled with `-O2`, `mainHim` takes 4.65s; `mainMe` takes 0.05s. The numbers for `mainMe` can be cut in half again by using the `PatriciaTree` graph implementation rather than the default one, and probably cut still farther with profiling and some thought. Just in case the reason `mainMe` is so much faster is that it is finding so many fewer graphs, I tested a modified `main` as well:

```
main = print . length . concat . take 8 . levels $ (search (mkUUGraph c60) :: Tree (Gr () ()))
```

This prints 35853, so it is finding roughly the same number of graphs as your test command. It takes 0.72s in ghci and 0.38s when compiled with `-O2`.

Answer (score 0):

> Or the best solution is porting it on C, and write bindings to C library over FFI?

No, you don't have to write it in C. The code generated by GHC is not that much slower than C. This huge speed difference suggests that you're implementing a different algorithm. So instead of rewriting in a different language, you should rewrite the Haskell code.

I guess the problem with your code is that you ...

1. use lists instead of sets
2. use breadth-first instead of depth-first enumeration (not sure)
3. use operations on the whole set of edges instead of cleverly keeping track of which edges are in which set
4. encode the recursive structure of the algorithm by hand, instead of using recursive calls.

I have to admit that I don't fully understand your code. But I read the paper you linked to, and the algorithm described there seems to be a simple brute-force enumeration of all results. So I guess the Haskell implementation should use the list monad (or list comprehensions) to enumerate all subgraphs, filtering out non-connected subgraphs during the enumeration. If you've never written code with the list monad before, just enumerating all subgraphs might be a good starting point.